# Wilson confidence interval for partially-paired data

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, paired-data

I have a data set with paired observations (before and after a specific intervention). There are a lot of metrics in this data set, some of them numeric (of unknown distribution) and some of them boolean (binomially distributed), and each of these has a "before" and "after" value. For some pairs, either the "before" or "after" values are missing.

## Numeric metrics

To deal with the missing observations for numeric metrics, we've been using a T-test based on Looney and Jones (2003):

If we define:

- $a_{all}$ the data set containing all values of the "after" side value of a particular metric.
- $b_{all}$ the data set containing all values of the "before" side value of the metric.
- $a_{both}$ the data set containing values of the "after" side value of the metric, where a the metric is not missing for either side of the pair.
- $b_{both}$ the data set containing all values of the "before" side value of the metric, where a the metric is not missing for either side of the pair.
- $|x$| is the number of observations in data set $x$ (any of the above datasets). In particular $|a_{both}| = |b_{both}|$.

$$M_{diff} = mean(a_{all})-mean(b_{all})$$
$$SE(M_{diff}) = \sqrt{\frac{var(a_{all})}{|a_{all}|} + \frac{var(b_{all})}{|b_{all}|}- \frac{2|a_{both}|cov(a_{both},b_{both})}{|a_{all}||b_{all}|}}$$

The calculation for degress of freedom is unimportant for this question, but it's based on Mehrotra (2004).

For T-intervals, variances and covariaces are sample variances, computed with a denominator of n-1.

## Boolean (binomial) metrics

To deal with the boolean metrics, we're using Wald confidence intervals, which are a simple that's taught in introductory statistics courses or Statistics AP.

For single-proportion Z-intervals, that's $\hat{p} \pm \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$

They don't teach two-proportion Z-intervals with paired observations in introductory statistics courses, but it's pretty simple to compute the variance of the paired differences using $var(a-b) = var(a)+var(b)-2cov(a,b)$.

It's also pretty simple to deal with missing observations in the paired case by applying the variance formula from Looney and Jones (2003), which I wrote above.

## Now my question

Some of the boolean metrics that I measure have means that are very close to 1 or 0. In many cases they have fewer than 5 successes, so the Wald confidence intervals are not appropriate. However, we'd like to analyse these metrics know when a particular intervention moves one of these metrics from fewer than 5 successes to more than 5 successes, and we'd like to have an accurate confidence interval around the magnitude of the movement.

The [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) looks appropriate. But how do I adapt that for paired observations? How do I adapt that for observations with one side missing?

## References

- Looney SW, Jones PW. A method for comparing two normal means using combined samples of correlated and uncorrelated data. Stat Med. 2003 May 15;22(9):1601-10. doi: 10.1002/sim.1514. PMID: 12704618.
- Mehrotra DV. A method for comparing two normal means using combined samples of correlated and uncorrelated data by S. W. Looney and P. W. Jones, Statistics in Medicine 2003; 22:1601-1610. Stat Med. 2004 Apr 15;23(7):1179-80. doi: 10.1002/sim.1693. PMID: 15057885.

Comment: On second thought, Wilson intervals might not be appropriate, because they're not symmetric. So I guess I also want to know if there's a symmetric interval that's more apporpriate than the Wald interval, too.

Comment: Thinking about it more: if your proportion is too close to 1 or 0, symmetric confidence interval is impossible. I guess my preference for a symmetric interval is just a user interface issue -- it's more consise to report the confidence interval as $\hat{p} \pm s$, rather than $\hat{p}, (b,c)$, and I can figure out the UI for an asymmetric interval if necessary.